# ListView Crashes When invoke the adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I created a `ListView` and it shows the result from `AsyncTask`. The result was obtained (can see in log) but when instaled on mobile it crashes when invoking the `Adapter`. But it will work on Emulator.

```
07-24 14:50:01.484    7284-7284/wisilica.com.pling E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: wisilica.com.pling, PID: 7284
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers(GLES20Canvas.java:1439)
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLines(GLES20Canvas.java:1019)
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLine(GLES20Canvas.java:1009)
            at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:538)
            at android.widget.ListView.drawDivider(ListView.java:3384)
            at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3279)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4064)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2401)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2273)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1903)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1020)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5762)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang
```

Comment: Please give more details... Can't do much with just a stacktrace....

Comment: Please try to modify the adapter in ui thread